# Adding content to Google knowledge panel

Tags: google-search, google

I recently verified my [Google knowledge panel](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel#topic=9164489). As I am not a celebrity, the panel has very little info (only title and education). There is a help article on how to [update the knowledge panel](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/7534842?hl=en), but that only covers how to edit existing info. For example, it covers how to edit the featured image, but it assumes that an image already exists ("On the image, click Edit"). Is there a way to add new info?

For social media specifically, it says: "Eligible entities will be able to suggest the addition of new, or edit existing, social profiles". This is slightly helpful as at least it suggests there is a multi-tier system (eligible and not eligible entities).

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Have you already tried this [Get verified on Google](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/7534902?hl=en)?

Comment: How about this [Update your Google knowledge panel](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/7534842?=en)?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I got verified and I linked to that same article.

Answer (score 1):

The only information you can actually [add to a panel](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/7534842?=en) are social media links. The rest can only be updated. If you're not famous enough, you simply don't have those options. For example, [I can only change my featured image](https://www.google.com/search?q=You+Liang+%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3), but not add more related images.